# Node use variables from another file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have long list of variables at the beginning of my single file app. How can I move variables to another file and use them from there. 
Can I do that without requiring them as modules?

My code is written like this so I need variables to work just like the would be in the same file.

```
const1 = 'apple'
const2 = 'banana'
const3 = 'pear'
…

let1 = const1

console.log(let1)
```

and that should output apple.

And I want move those const variables from top

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

You have to export the variable in vars.js

```js
let const1 = 'apple'
exports.const1 = const1;
```

And then access via:

```js
var request = require(./vars.js);
...
let x = request.const1;
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a good practice but you can declare the variables as properties of the global object...

```
global.const1 = 'apple'
global.const2 = 'banana'
global.const3 = 'pear'
…

let1 = global.const1

console.log(let1)
```

Comment: Just make sure you require your global variables file before any other module.